# trailing options found on command line ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpeg complains about trailing options. What parameters are out of the order. I am unable to find any. Please point out some.

```
 /home/ec2-user/bin/ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 1024 -probesize 18M 
    -re -f rawvideo -framerate 1 -pixel_format rgb32 -video_size 1920x1080 
    -i pipe:0 -i /home/ec2-user/logo.png 
    -i /home/ec2-user/testdata/audio.m4a -ss 0 -t 20 
    -filter_complex "[0:v]vflip[main];[1:v]scale=1920/10:-1[si], [main][si]overlay=5:5:format=rgb,format=yuv420p" 
    -c:v libx264 /home/ec2-user/output.mp4 
    -c:v copy -shortest
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basic FFmpeg syntax structure is

```
ffmpeg -<options for input 1> -i input 1 -<options for input 2> -i input 2 -<options for output 1> output1 -<options for output 2> output2
```

(Global options can go anywhere)

So,

```
 /home/ec2-user/bin/ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 1024 -probesize 18M 
    -re -f rawvideo -framerate 1 -pixel_format rgb32 -video_size 1920x1080 
    -i pipe:0 -i /home/ec2-user/logo.png 
    -i /home/ec2-user/testdata/audio.m4a -ss 0 -t 20 
    -filter_complex "[0:v]vflip[main];[1:v]scale=1920/10:-1[si], [main][si]overlay=5:5:format=rgb,format=yuv420p" 
    -c:v libx264 -shortest /home/ec2-user/output.mp4
```

Shortest goes before the output filename. The `-c:v copy` overrides the `libx264` specified just before and does not make sense for output to MP4, so I've removed it.

Comment: I am getting the same error message when I execute `ffmpeg -i sample.opus -f wav   | xargs [something]`. Any suggestions why? I want to pipe a wav file into [something] using xargs.

Comment: If that paste is accurate, you're missing the output URL token. Add  `pipe:1` after the `wav`.